# What's the use of \$$ in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I found this as a suggestion of how to store the output of "eval" into a variable called line.  So, what's the use of `\$$`?

```
command = "some command"
line = $(eval \$$command)
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Try running this with `set -x` and see if it makes sense to you. Hint: escaping the character $ cause it to become literal. Moreover, don't put commands in variables. Variables hold data, **functions** hold code.

Comment: Regarding @RanyAlbegWein's comment, see [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\$` prevents the shell from trying to treat the `$` as the beginning of a parameter expansion. However, the code as a whole doesn't do anything useful. After fixing the whitespace issues and adding a real command to the example, your code looks like

```
command="ls -l"
line=$(eval \$$command)
```

`command` is simply a string `ls -l`. To evaluate the next line, the shell first evaluates the command substitution. The first step is to expand the parameter `command`, yielding `line=$(eval \$ls -l)`. Quote removal gets rid of the backslash, so `eval` receives the arguments `$ls` and `-l`. Since `ls` presumably is not a variable, `$ls` is expanded to the empty string, and `eval` is left simply with `-l` to execute. There being no such command, you get an error.

You *might* think, then, that the correct form is simply

```
line=$(eval $command)
```

or slightly better

```
line=$(eval "$command")
```

That will work for *simple* cases, but not in general. This has been hashed over many times in many questions; see Bash FAQ 50, ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for the details.

---

To answer the literal question, though, `\$$` is useful for outputing the string `$$`, instead of expanding it to the current process ID:

```
# The exact output will vary
$ echo $$
86542

# Literal quotes
$ echo \$\$
$$

# Escaping either quote is sufficient
$ echo \$$ $\$
$$ $$
```